# How to separate Android & iOS Xamarin UI Test Results

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I have some Xamarin UI Tests which have the Attributes

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
```

Enabling me to run both platform tests in the cloud (AppCenter Test), however, when I get the XML NUnit test results I have problems because I have **inconclusive** tests.

E.g. Say I have 15 Android tests passing if I publish the XML tests results to Azure DevOps Pipeline it will say only 50% of my tests passed with 15 inconclusive.

[image]

What I want to know is what I can do to separate these tests entirely so I end up with an tests result **only** for Android and for iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running these tests via the app center?

Comment: yes I am @MosheMoadeb

Comment: so when running tests on app center, you should have one app for ios and one app for Android since you are dealing with an iPA and an APK is that not the case for your project?